# Many timer jobs inside our sharepoint on-premises 2013 is showing "N/A" for the "Last Run"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, central-administration, sharepoint-on-prem, timer-jobs

We have an enterprise sharepoint on-premises 2013.  but recently i have noted that many jobs inside the sharepoint central admin site are having their "Last Run" = "N/A" as follow:-

[image]

Now the timer service is working well, as per this picture:-

[image]

I also tried to do a IIS reset and restart the hosting server, without any fix.

Answer (score 0):

In the edit timer job page, make sure you have enable this timer job. And change the schedule with a few minutes and click run now.

[image]

Then check if there is a record for this timer job in Job History list. If so, check the Status, and if the status is not succeeded, click it and check if there is error message in the table.

If the issue exists, clear SharePoint Configuration Cache and restart SharePoint Timer Service.

Then re-run SharePoint 2013 product configuration Wizard and check again.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to check:

- Make Sure `SharePoint Timer Services` & `SharePoint Administration Services` are Running on all servers in the farm
- Make Sure "Dead Site Delete" timer job is not disabled
- Try to Restart the Timer Service from services console on all SharePoint server.
- try to run this script in powershell: `Start-SPAdminJob -verbose`
- Hit the Run Now and look ULS logs, in case it is not updating.