# SharePoint 2013 On Premises fires multiple emails for one trigger

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, email

I am absolutely sure our custom workflows fires only one time but sends multiple duplicate emails every 1 minute (exactly every 60 seconds, i saw it from exchange logs).

Which is the timer job that trigger this mechanism?

I suspect is running multiple times, one for each farm servers.

The closest thing i found to my problem is: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2011/11/13/sharepoint-timer-job-locks-and-scope/

thanks

Comment: How did you design your custom workflow? Is it a SharePoint Designer workflow? please provide a screenshot about your workflow structure to analysis further.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the Sharepoint Timer Service?  [This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/259924/many-timer-jobs-inside-our-sharepoint-on-premises-2013-is-showing-n-a-for-the) might help.

The Windows Task Scheduler can also be used to configure the start conditions to run powershell scripts - for instance I've used this to trigger a Designer workflow that sends out an email reminder if the Reminder Date = Today's Date.  If you have something like this set up, but mis-configured then it could trigger multiple emails...(I'm just trying to suggest another avenue of investigation).

### Further Info on Timer Jobs

[Link 1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-view-timer-job-status-in-sharepoint-2013-central-administration/)

[Link 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116418/changing-sharepoint-weekly-timer-job-to-daily-via-central-administration)

Or do an internet search on "sharepoint 2013 configure timer job in central administration" and you should find something useful.